# How align labels in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I just started using Bootstrap (actually BootstrapVue) and I do not know what is the correct way to vertically align labels. Before jumping into some flex/groid experiments i wanted to make sure there is no built in solution.

Specifically, the code

```
<template>
    <b-container class="bv-example-row" fluid>
        <b-row>
            <b-col sm="2">
                <label for="input-large">Title:</label>
            </b-col>
            <b-col sm="10">
                <b-form-input id="input-large" size="lg" placeholder="" v-model="incident.title"></b-form-input>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
</template>
```

produces this output, where "Title:" is not vertically aligned with the input box.

[image]

**Is this something I should try to correct myself (using alignement techniques from flex/grid), or is this handled by Bootstrap?**

Comment: I think you probably need to use the forms component to align the items. Specifically, horizontal layout. See this: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-group/

Answer (score 4):

From the [Bootstrap Vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/form-group/) Documentation:

```
<b-form-group label-cols="4" label-cols-lg="2" label="Title" label-for="input-default" label-align="right">
  <b-form-input id="input-default"></b-form-input>
</b-form-group>
```

There are other classes which you can also define for different breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Using `<b-form-group>` is your best bet, but you can also use the `align-v` prop of `<b-row>`

```html
    <b-container class="bv-example-row" fluid>
        <b-row align-v="center">
            <b-col sm="2">
                <label for="input-large">Title:</label>
            </b-col>
            <b-col sm="10">
                <b-form-input id="input-large" size="lg" placeholder="" v-model="incident.title"></b-form-input>
            </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </b-container>
```